# log messages appearing twice with Python Logging

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using Python logging, and for some reason, all of my messages are appearing twice.

I have a module to configure logging:

```
# BUG: It's outputting logging messages twice - not sure why - it's not the propagate setting.
def configure_logging(self, logging_file):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    self.logger.propagate = 0
    # Format for our loglines
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    # Setup console logging
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.addHandler(ch)
    # Setup file logging as well
    fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Later on, I call this method to configure logging:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tom = Boy()
    tom.configure_logging(LOG_FILENAME)
    tom.buy_ham()
```

And then within say, the buy_ham module, I'd call:

```
self.logger.info('Successfully able to write to %s' % path)
```

And for some reason, all the messages are appearing twice. I commented out one of the stream handlers, still the same thing. Bit of a weird one, not sure why this is happening. I'm assuming I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Are you sure `configure_logging()` is not called twice (e.g. from the constructor too)? Is only one instance of Boy() created?

Comment: Using `self.logger.handlers = [ch]` instead would solve this problem, though it would be best just to ensure that you don't run this code twice by, for example, using `if not self.logger` at the start.

Comment: Check this out, don't forget to name your handlers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76941199/10389449

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You are calling `configure_logging` twice (maybe in the `__init__` method of `Boy`) : `getLogger` will return the same object, but `addHandler` does not check if a similar handler has already been added to the logger.

Try tracing calls to that method and eliminating one of these. Or set up a flag `logging_initialized` initialized to `False` in the `__init__` method of `Boy` and change `configure_logging` to do nothing if `logging_initialized` is `True`, and to set it to `True` after you've initialized the logger.

If your program creates several `Boy` instances, you'll have to change the way you do things with a global `configure_logging` function adding the handlers, and the `Boy.configure_logging` method only initializing the `self.logger` attribute.

Another way of solving this is by checking the handlers attribute of your logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
if not logger.handlers:
    # create the handlers and call logger.addHandler(logging_handler)
```

Comment: Yes, you were right - silly me. I called it in __init__, as well as explicitly elsewhere. Lol. Thanks =).

Comment: In my case, they were appearing 6 times. I had suspected that because I've declared the same type of logger in 6 oop classes

Comment: I'd like to share here my experience: for a Flask application which I developed, the log messages were appearing MORE THAN TWICE. I'd say that they were incrementing on the log file, due to the fact that, when the application and the modules were loaded, the `logger` variable used, was not the one instantiated from one of my classes, but the `logger` variable present on Python3 cache, and the handler was added every 60 sec by an AppScheduler which I configured. So, this `if not logger.handlers` is a pretty smart way to avoid this type of phenomenon. Thanks for the solution, comrade :)!

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in my Flask app. This solution fixed the problem for log messages generated in the main flask app, but my app cals functions in a library module, and those messages from that library are still getting logged multiple times. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: i had a different solution which fixed for me. i had a file config and had propagate set to 1 there for  logger. i removed it and it fixed the issue. if possible , can someone please  explain me why. since issue is fixed, i did not open a new thread

Answer (score 111):

If you are seeing this problem and you're not adding the handler twice then see abarnert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127360/python-2-7-log-displayed-twice-when-logging-module-is-used-in-two-python-scri)

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate):

> Note: If you attach a handler to a logger and one or more of its
> ancestors, it may emit the same record multiple times. In general, you
> should not need to attach a handler to more than one logger - if you
> just attach it to the appropriate logger which is highest in the
> logger hierarchy, then it will see all events logged by all descendant
> loggers, provided that their propagate setting is left set to True. A
> common scenario is to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to
> let propagation take care of the rest.

So, if you want a custom handler on "test", and you don't want its messages also going to the root handler, the answer is simple: turn off its `propagate` flag:

```py
logger.propagate = False
```

Comment: That's the best answer. It did not fit the purpose of the poster (logical error in coding) but most of the times, this should be the case.

Comment: Bravo. THIS is the actual cause of the duplicates (for the most general cases).

Comment: Why cant this be default. I build all my loggers under "root." + directory structure, so I can easily control everything from the 'root' logger

Comment: This is what helped me understand that this is the right answer (if it's not a code bug that is): https://jdhao.github.io/2020/06/20/python_duplicate_logging_messages/

Answer (score 14):

I'm a python newbie, but this seemed to work for me (Python 2.7)

```
while logger.handlers:
     logger.handlers.pop()
```

Comment: This worked for me, but prefer using logger.handlers.clear()

Answer (score 12):

In my case I'd to set `logger.propagate = False` to prevent double printing.

In below code if you remove `logger.propagate = False` then you will see double printing.

```
import logging
from typing import Optional

_logger: Optional[logging.Logger] = None

def get_logger() -> logging.Logger:
    global _logger
    if _logger is None:
        raise RuntimeError('get_logger call made before logger was setup!')
    return _logger

def set_logger(name:str, level=logging.DEBUG) -> None:
    global _logger
    if _logger is not None:
        raise RuntimeError('_logger is already setup!')
    _logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    _logger.handlers.clear()
    _logger.setLevel(level)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(level)
    # warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "(Possibly )?corrupt EXIF data", UserWarning)
    ch.setFormatter(_get_formatter())
    _logger.addHandler(ch)
    _logger.propagate = False # otherwise root logger prints things again


def _get_formatter() -> logging.Formatter:
    return logging.Formatter(
        '[%(asctime)s] [%(name)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
```

Comment: This is the issue I have. Thank you

Comment: Great answer; adding `logger.propagate = False` was the solution to prevent double logging in a Flask application hosted by Waitress, when logging to Flask's `app.logger` instance.

Answer (score 8):

The handler is added each time you call from outside. Try Removeing the Handler after you finish your job:

```
self.logger.removeHandler(ch)
```

Comment: I used `logger.handlers.pop() ` in python 2.7, does the trick

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if you are trying to create a logging object from the parent file. For e.g.
This is the main application file `test.py`

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

def my_code():
# 'application' code
    logger.debug('debug message')
    logger.info('info message')
    logger.warning('warn message')
    logger.error('error message')
    logger.critical('critical message')
```

And below is the parent file `main.py`

```
import test

test.my_code()
```

The output of this will print only once

```
2021-09-26 11:10:20,514 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2021-09-26 11:10:20,514 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2021-09-26 11:10:20,514 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2021-09-26 11:10:20,514 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2021-09-26 11:10:20,514 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
```

But if we had a parent logging object, then it will be printed twice. For e.g. if this is the parent file

```
import test
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


test.my_code()
```

The the output will be

```
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
2021-09-26 11:16:28,679 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to others' useful responses...

**In case you are NOT accidentally configuring more than one handler on your logger**:

When your logger has ancestors(root logger is always one) and they have their own handlers, they will also output when your logger outputs (by default), which will create duplicates. You have **two** options:

- Don't propagate your log event to your ancestors by setting:

```py
my_logger.propagate = False
```

- If you only have one ancestor(root logger), you could directly configure their handler instead. For example:

```py
# directly change the formatting of root's handler
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
roots_handler = root_logger.handlers[0]
roots_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(': %(message)s')) # change format

my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger') # my_logger will use new formatting
```

Answer (score 2):

A call to `logging.debug()` calls `logging.basicConfig()` if there are no root handlers installed. That was happening for me in a test framework where I couldn't control the order that test cases fired. My initialization code was installing the second one. The default uses logging.BASIC_FORMAT that I didn't want.

Comment: I think this is what's going on for me.  How do you prevent the automatic creation of console loggers?

Comment: @Robert it's about making sure you're initialized with the logger you want, before the first logging call. Testing frameworks can obscure this, but there should be a way to do it. Also, if you're multiprocessing you have to do the same with each process.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you output something to the logger (accidentally) then configure it, it is too late.  For example, in my code I had

```
logging.warning("look out)"

...
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(ch)

root.info("hello")
```

I would get something like (ignoring the format options)

```
look out
hello
hello
```

and everything was written to stdout twice.  I believe this is because the first call to `logging.warning` creates a new handler automatically, and then I explicitly added another handler. The problem went away when I removed the accidental first `logging.warning` call.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue in the context of multiple processes. (For the code see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) which I was following almost verbatim.) Namely, all log messages originating from any of the child processes got duplicated.

My mistake was to call `worker_configurer()`,

```
def worker_configurer(logging_queue):
    queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(logging_queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(queue_handler)
    root.setLevel(level)
```

both in the child processes *and also* in the main process (since I wanted the main process to log stuff, too). The reason this led to trouble (on my Linux machine) is that on Linux the child processes got started through forking and therefore inherited the existing log handlers from the main process. That is, on Linux the `QueueHandler` got registered twice.

Now, preventing the `QueueHandler` from getting registered twice in the `worker_configurer()` function is not as trivial as it seems:

- Logger objects like the root logger `root` have a `handlers` property but it is undocumented.
- In my experience, testing whether `any([handler is queue_handler for handler in root.handlers])` (identity) or `any([handler == queue_handler for handler in root.handlers])` (equality) fails after forking, even if `root.handlers` seemingly contains the same `QueueHandler`. (Obviously, the previous two expressions can be abbreviated by `queue_handler in root.handlers`, since the `in` operator [checks for both identity and equality in the case of lists](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).)
- The root logger gets modified by packages like pytest, so `root.handlers` and `root.hasHandlers()` are not very reliable to begin with. (They are global state, after all.)

The clean solution, therefore, is to replace forking with spawning to prevent these kinds of multiprocessing bugs right from the start (provided you can live with the additional memory footprint, of course). Or to use an alternative to the `logging` package that doesn't rely on global state and instead requires you to do proper dependency injection but I'm digressing… :)

With that being said, I ended up going for a rather trivial check:

```
def worker_configurer(logging_queue):
    queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(logging_queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()

    for handler in root.handlers:
        if isinstance(handler, logging.handlers.QueueHandler):
            return

    root.addHandler(queue_handler)
    root.setLevel(level)
```

Obviously, this will have nasty side effects the second I decide to register a second queue handler somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> "Loggers have the following attributes and methods. Note that Loggers should NEVER be instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function logging.getLogger(name).
> ***Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object".***

Make sure you don't initialise your loggers with the same name
I advise you to initialise the logger with `__name__` as name param i.e:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

***NOTE:***
even if you init a loggers from other modules with same name, you will still get the same logger, therefore calling i.e `logger.info('somthing')` will log as many times as you initiated the logger class.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things and finally came up with my custom logger. You just need to `copy` and `paste` it in your code and it will do the work you required.

**Why to use?**

> 1. No repeated logs.
> 2. Separate customisation for info logs - [ Not contains path and unnecessary details ]
> 3. Different colours to different log levels.
> 4. You will get all the different levels of logs - [ info, warning, error, critical, debug ,... ].

```
import logging


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def format(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            self._style._fmt = "%(levelname)-5s  %(asctime)-3s %(message)s"
        else:
            color = {
                logging.WARNING: 33,
                logging.ERROR: 31,
                logging.FATAL: 31,
                # logging.DEBUG: 36
            }.get(record.levelno, 0)
            self._style._fmt = f'\033[{color}m%(levelname)-5s %(asctime)s file/"%(pathname)10s", line %(lineno)d in "%(funcName)s" -> "%(message)s" \033[0m'
        return super().format(record)


logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger")
if not logger.handlers:
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter())
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.propagate = False
    # to disable any level of logs; eg - disabled debug level logs.
    logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

**What you will get** [ *it will be with different colours in you colsole/log file ]

logger.info("This is info log")

> INFO 2023-03-24 20:11:51,230 This is info log

logger.warning("This is warning log")

> WARNING 2023-03-24 20:11:51,230 file/"/home/xyz/abc", line 25 in "my_function" -> "This is warning log"

logger.error("This is error log")

> ERROR 2023-03-24 20:11:51,230 file/"/home/xyz/abc", line 26 in "my_function" -> "This is error log"

logger.critical("This is critical log")

> CRITICAL 2023-03-24 20:11:51,231 file/"/home/xyz/abc", line 27 in "my_function" -> "This is critical log"

logger.debug("This is debug log")

> DEBUG 2023-03-24 20:11:51,231 file/"/home/xyz/abc", line 28 in "my_function" -> "This is debug log"

**Note -** I have disabled the debug level log in the above code, to use comment/remove the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a strange situation where console logs were doubled but my file logs were not.  After a ton of digging I figured it out.

Please be aware that third party packages can register loggers.  This is something to watch out for (and in some cases can't be prevented).  In many cases third party code checks to see if there are any existing *root* logger handlers; and if there isn't--they register a new console handler.

My solution to this was to register my console logger at the root level:

```
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()  # note no text passed in--that's how we grab the root logger
if not rootLogger.handlers:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(process)s|%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
        rootLogger.addHandler(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any config for logging, For instance `log.conf`

In .conf file you can do it by adding this line in the `[logger_myLogger]` section: `propagate=0`

```
[logger_myLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=validate,consoleHandler
qualname=VALIDATOR
propagate=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard construction `logger = logging.getLogger('mymodule')` and then accidentally mistype `loggger` as `logging` i.e.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('mymodule')

# configure your handlers

logger.info("my info message")  # won't make duplicate 
logging.info("my info message")  # will make duplicate logs
```

then this will cause duplicate messages to come up because the call to `logging` creates a new logger.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was not due to handlers or duplicate initial configuration but a stupid typo. In `main.py` I was using a `logger` object but in `my_tool.py` I was directly calling to the `logging` module by mistake, hence after invoking functions from `my_tool` module everything was messed up and the messages appeared duplicated.

This was the code:

`main.py`

```
import logging
import my_tool

logger_name = "cli"
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

logger.info("potato")
logger.debug("potato)
my_tool.function()
logger.info("tomato")
```

`my_tool.py`

```
import logging
logger_name = "cli"
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
# some code
logging.info("carrot")
```

and the result

`terminal`

```
>> potato
>> potato
>> carrot
>> tomato
>> tomato
```