# Trouble with duplicate lines of logs in log file

Tags: python

I've been trying to get this working correctly all day, its nearly complete just a strange issue I'm getting. Every result that is found in the search query gets logged as expected but the first result gets logged once, the second gets logged twice, the third gets logged three times etc.

Any ideas how to get rid of the duplicates? [Example of logs](http://postimage.org/image/s0uqsh6dd/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import simplejson 
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'test'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' \
      % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']
for i in results:
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.0.2', 514)))
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
    logging.warn(i['url'])
    print i['url']
```

Comment: same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729268/python-logging-messages-appearing-twice

Comment: @Gurney: I disagree, that question has every line doubled. The _answer_ might be relatively similar but they are different enough questions that I think the "duplicate" isn't quite right.

Comment: @sarnold: well, I won't argue with you there, but IMO it's the same question: the code adds a handler more than one time, and as a result you get duplicated log output. The way you call addHandler several times matters little in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're adding a new handler each time in the for loop. Do this outside the loop, then only do the actual `logging.warn` inside the loop.

Comment: well its not answered yet thats why its not shown as such if i only have the logging.warn(i['url']) in the loop it failes to write to the syslog

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem, but I needed to add a new handler each time in the for loop. So removing handler inside a loop didn't help me.

When you create handler like this:

```
hdl = logging.FileHandler("hits.log")
```

you need to remove it like this:

```
logger.removeHandler(hdl)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have not accepted the answer, as Daniel said, you need to have

```
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.0.2', 514)))
```

outside the `for loop`.