# Tensorflow causes logging messages to double

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, python-logging

So I was playing around with Google's [Tensorflow](http://www.tensorflow.org/) library they published yesterday and encountered an annoying bug that keeps biting me.

What I did was setup the python logging functions as I usually do, and the result was that, if I import the tensorflow library, all messages in the console started doubling. Interestingly, this does *not* happen if you just use the `logging.warn/info/..()` function.

An example of a code that does *not* double the messages:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

logging.warn('test')
```

An example of a code that *does* double all messages:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('TEST')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.warn('test')
```

Now, I'm a simple man. I like the functionality of `logging`, so I use it. The setup with the `logger` object and the adding of a `StreamHandler` is something I picked up looking at how other people did this, but it looks like it fits with how the thing was meant to be used. However, I do not have in-depth knowledge of the logging library, as it always just kind of worked.

So, any help explaining why the doubling of the messages occurs will be most helpful.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with Python 2.7.6, but the error happens in all Python 2.7 versions I tried.

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating this on ubuntu 14.04 also with python 2.7.6:

    python testlog.py
    WARNING:root:test

Can you provide a bit more detail about how you installed tf?

Comment: Ah!  There's a typo in your sample code.  The last line should be logger.warn('test') instead of logging.warn.  Now I've replicated it.  And the answer is a bit more clear - hang on.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I get this output:

```
test
WARNING:TEST:test
```

Tensorflow is *also* using the logging framework and has set up its own handlers, so when you log, by default, it propagates up to the parent logging handlers inside tensorflow.  You can change this behavior by setting:

```py
logger.propagate = False
```

See also [duplicate output in simple python logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561058/duplicate-output-in-simple-python-logging-configuration)

Followup: This was an unintended side-effect of the way tensorflow was using the logging package. I've changed it at HEAD to scope its internal loggers under the name "tensorflow" to avoid this pollution. Should be in the github head within a day or so. In the meantime, the logger.propagate solution will work and won't break once that fix is in, so you should be safe to go. Thanks again for spotting this!

Followup-Followup:
Starting with [TensorFlow 1.14](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_logger) exposes the `logger` directly:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

logger = tf.get_logger()
```

Comment: (I'm going to check whether this is actually intended or a bug - I've never encountered it or thought too much about it.)

Comment: Tensorflow isn't using the logging package in the standard way of doing getLogger(__name__), which is why you're seeing that namespace collision.  I'll send a patch for this and see if we can get it happier.  Thanks for asking about this!

Comment: Something like the earlier doubling effect can still happen in REPLs. Not a problem, but could be surprising. I wrote up a little [post on logging](http://planspace.org/20170322-tensorflow_logging/) and describe that phenomenon more there.

Comment: @dga shouldn't this be fixed? Expierencing the issue again in TensorFlow 2.X

Answer (score 2):

`logger.propagate = False` solved my problem. I think this is a bug of tensorflow

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the accepted answer?