# Tensorflow logging messages doubled

Tags: tensorflow

Here is a program that causes doubled Tensorflow logging messages:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
tf.logging.info("tf version %s" % tf.__version__)
```

Output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:tf version 1.4.0
INFO:tensorflow:tf version 1.4.0
```

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664610/34935) says to 1) to turn off logger propagation on the custom logger; 2) it will be fixed soon (in Nov 2015, over two years ago).

I wanted to turn off log message propagation on the Tensorflow logger, and found [this post](https://planspace.org/20170322-tensorflow_logging/) that suggested the following as a hack just for a REPL (i.e. interactively):

```py
tf.logging._logger.propagate = False
```

Works like a charm.

But .. is there a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately `tf.logging._logger.propagate = False` does not work for me. Same for `tf.logging.propagate = False`