# TensorFlow prints log information twice

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running TensorFlow official model from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official

When I run the official resnet model, each tensorflow INFO message is printed twice as displayed below:

```
INFO:tensorflow:cross_entropy = 2.053623, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.19732143 (0.102 sec)
I0927 11:58:25.770764 140597122463552 basic_session_run_hooks.py:247] cross_entropy = 2.053623, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.19732143 (0.102 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:cross_entropy = 1.7440678, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.19938381 (0.107 sec)
I0927 11:58:25.878196 140597122463552 basic_session_run_hooks.py:247] cross_entropy = 1.7440678, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.19938381 (0.107 sec)                                                                                   
INFO:tensorflow:cross_entropy = 2.116714, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.1983507 (0.102 sec)
I0927 11:58:25.980251 140597122463552 basic_session_run_hooks.py:247] cross_entropy = 2.116714, learning_rate = 0.025, train_accuracy = 0.1983507 (0.102 sec)
```

My current log level is

`export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2`

Can someone help with the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `logger.propagate = False`?

Comment: How can I set this? Is this an environment variable?

Comment: It's in your training code. When you get tensorflow logger, set this property to false.

Comment: Thanks, however I couldn't manage to find this parameter. I'm using TF-1.13. Could you please share some doc for this?

Comment: Could you check this post, looks like they have the same issue as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662648/tensorflow-causes-logging-messages-to-double