# Why Flask logger does not log in docker when using UWSGI in front?

Tags: python, docker, logging, flask, uwsgi

I have a `Flask` application inside of `Docker` that was logging into `docker logs` when it was running without `UWSGI` in front. Now I have used `UWSGI` with the config below to run my application inside of `Docker`:

```
[uwsgi]

master = true

processes = 5
threads = 2

socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chmod-socket = 664
stats=0.0.0.0:30310

chdir = /etc/fantas

uid = root
gid = root

wsgi-file=uwsgi_fantas.py
callable=app

vacuum = true
```

The `uwsgi_fantas.py` file contains:

```
from fantas.fantas_app import FantasApp

app = FantasApp().setup()
```

The `setup` method returns `app`:

```
from flask_restful import Api
from fantas import app

class FantasApp(object):
    def setup(self):
        api = Api(app)
        api.add_resource(Token, '/users')

        return app
```

Finally the part that initiates the `Flask` framework is inside of `__init__.py` in the root directory of project:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

s_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
s_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(s_handler)
```

As `UWSGI` works directly with the `app` object I have configured logger inside of `__init__.py`, but the problem is that it does not log anything into `Docker` when it is run, it just logs `UWSGI` requests.

What is wrong in the process of app.logger configuration?

**Problem has been solved, but now logs get duplicated!**

---

**EDIT-1:**
I set `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` and it seems that `Flask` logs into `Docker` successfully. The weird part is that it logs 3 times! I removed all logger configs and handlers and just used:

```
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But now it logs 2 times:

```
proj_fantas.1.huagnqqpzo1n@linuxkit-025000000001    | [2018-07-13 07:02:38,008] DEBUG in token: [Token] authenticating user...
proj_fantas.1.huagnqqpzo1n@linuxkit-025000000001    | DEBUG:flask.app:[Token] authenticating user...
```

Why it is like that?

---

**EDIT-2:**

The output of `app.logger.handlers` is `[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f0f430ca8d0>]`. It just shows the StreamHandler that I initialized earlier, nothing more.

---

**EDIT-3:**

The output of `ps -ef` command inside of `Docker`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        10     1  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        12     1  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        13     1  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        15     1  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        16     1  0 15:26 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi uwsgi_coconuty.ini
root        20     0  0 15:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root       112    20  0 15:28 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

There is no other process running inside of `Docker`.

Comment: Do you have a minimal docker image/git repo or something one can directly use and debug?

Comment: The phrase "log into docker" makes it worth pointing out that the app (uwsgi) only need log to STDOUT|STDERR for output to make it to the docker log.  UWSGI [writes to STDOUT by default](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html) I suspect the StreamHandler() writing to a file or something "file-like" that is not where the container is watching for log output.

Comment: @TarunLalwani currently I don't have one, but I try to create one within the next couple of days. My problem as I have mentioned at the end of the question is that I have duplicate logs in `docker logs`. Read **EDIT-2** section.

Comment: @BoydHemphill first problem has been solved. If you read on the question you would see that I have problem on duplicate logs in docker logs. Read **EDIT-2** section plz. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ALH, however I came across this b/c of its title and did not find an answer yet.  Thus I offered an answer to the original question in case others find their way here.   If  you could provide your solution to the original question that would be super helpful!

Comment: Here is a SWAG on the second issue: Given that the messages are not identical, (one has a datestamp while the other does not), I assert there are multiple processes tied to STDOUT|STDERR. IIRC, it is possible to be running both the built in flask server and UWSGI. A way to check for this is to `docker exec` into the contain and then run the `ps` command.

Comment: @BoydHemphill, I have mentioned in **EDIT-1** section that by setting `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) ` problem gone away and logs appear in docker logs. I will do `ps` today and report the results.

Comment: @BoydHemphill could you kindly take a look at the section `EDIT-3`?

Comment: @ALH `ps` is showing only `uwsgi` process and nothing from `flask` so my above assertion is incorrect.  The answer from below is quite promising.

Comment: Is there even a way to avoid duplicate logging in debug mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, there are recent changes in the way Flask logs are initialized from version 0.9 to the current stable 1.0.2, for example. You can check this [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/commits/4309c7c6ea51e5797604c43ba858e5ebe1fb1674/flask/logging.py). I am assuming your docker image uses the most recent version.

If that is the case, even without any custom logging config,  actually it is logging for your output stream, but it is filtering out lower than WARNING logs (DEBUG and INFO). This happens when you rely on Flask initializing the log for you and you do not set a --debug flag (uwsgi case).

There are multiple strategies that can be looked at when you configure logging. One suggestion is to use the dictConfig initialization mentioned by the [library itself](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/), at the uwsgi master, before defining the app, which then forks. Following your example, at `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

app = Flask(__name__)
```

The problem you mention in **EDIT-1** looks like a python [logging propagation issue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate). There is a standalone case, easier to debug, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127360/python-2-7-log-displayed-twice-when-logging-module-is-used-in-two-python-scri?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Even though you have only set one Stream Handler, as your log shows, it probably has a parent attached. If you check for its parent it will probably have a handler attached **different** from the one you mentioned in **EDIT-2**
:

```
print logger.handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f15669c1550>]
print logger.parent.handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f15669c1610>]
```

This happens when the logging propagation is enabled and there happened some logging initialization elsewhere. You can check how propagation works by looking at `callHandlers` in [python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py):

```
    ...
    hdlr.handle(record)
    if not c.propagate:
        c = None    #break out
    else:
        c = c.parent
    ...
```

Back to your case (Flask), by looking at the traces in your logs, there is a logger named `flask.app`, which is the one created by [Flask itself](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/4309c7c6ea51e5797604c43ba858e5ebe1fb1674/flask/logging.py). There is the formatted version, and the unformatted one ([logging.BASIC_FORMAT](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5c4ca109af1c/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1640)), respectively. So it is probably being initialized somewhere in your code or in one of the libraries you import.

There are multiple ways you can solve this:

- Setting the propagation to false (easy solution, but workaround)
- Searching for the "invalid" configuration and removing it
- Use the dictConfig initialization, before instantiating the app, as the Flask logging tutorial suggests

Comment: By using `dictConfig`, app.logger works as expected, I really appreciate for the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (Special: I wanted to use the syslog). First I had to add a rule to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y rsyslog
service rsyslog start
```

Flask comes with build-in logging, so I just had to add some twigs

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
import logging.handlers

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = '/dev/log')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('flask [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Additional settings can be handled through the syslog-daemon