# Acces my Flask app logs directly in a Kubernetes pod

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I need to print the logs from my flask app in my Kubernetes pod.

Actually my Flask app renders logs in a file.config file and I can access it with the command : `kubectl exec -it podname /bin/bash` and all the logs are not written in this file.

How can I do to have the logs (GET, error messages, print...) directly when I use the command : `kubectl logs podname`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can access stderr/stdout logs of containers which running in a pod.

Therefore its actually not related to kubernetes.

check this. it might help. [Why Flask logger does not log in docker when using UWSGI in front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318988/why-flask-logger-does-not-log-in-docker-when-using-uwsgi-in-front)
You might want to look here. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/