# Python logger formatting is not formatting the string

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Following are the contents of `mylogger.py`:

```
def get_logger(name='my_super_logger'):
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    if not len(log.handlers):
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(ch)
    # print(id(log))
    return log
```

and following is contents of `myscript.py`:

```
from mylogger import get_logger

_logger = get_logger()

_logger.info('trying info')
_logger.debug('trying debug')
```

However I am facing two issues. It prints the logs twice and formatter is not working everytime:

```
09/18/2015 09:59:54 PM my_super_logger trying info 
INFO:my_super_logger:trying info 
09/18/2015 09:59:54 PM my_super_logger trying debug 
DEBUG:my_super_logger:trying debug
```

What exactly is the issue with my `get_logger` code?

I need a custom formatting. However I found out that without adding a handler I cannot add a `formatter`. So that's why I have added `StreamHandler`. And the reason for `if` block is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6729713/1382297). Without that, I would get duplicate log messages printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root logger is also emitting the message. Stop propagation up to the root with:

```
log.propagate = False
```

If you wanted to format *all* log output (so messages propagated up to the logger), set the formatter for the root logger.

You can do so with a [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) call provided nothing has yet been sent to the loggers, or by looping over the `logger.handlers` list of the root logger; you could pick out any `StreamHandlers` if you so wish:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()  # no name
for handler in root_logger.handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, logging.Streamhandler):
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of a custom handler, I had to call `format` manually.

I create a handler here

```py
    logger_config = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": {
            "standard": {"format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"},
        },
        "handlers": {
            "sns": {
                "formatter": "standard",
                "class": "app_logging.SnsHandler.SnsHandler",
                "log_level": os.environ.get("SNS_LOG_LEVEL") or "WARNING",
                "topic_arn": os.environ.get("SNS_LOG_TOPIC") or "hghghjg",
            }
        },
        "level": os.environ.get("LOG_LEVEL") or "DEBUG",
        # Root logger
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                "formatter": "standard",
                "handlers": ["sns"],
                "level": os.environ.get("LOG_LEVEL") or "DEBUG",
            },
        },
    }
    dictConfig(logger_config)
```

My handler class is here

```py
from logging import Handler
import boto3


class SnsHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, log_level, topic_arn: str, region: str = "us-east-1") -> None:
        super().__init__(log_level)
        self.topic_arn = topic_arn
        self._sns_client = boto3.client("sns", region_name=region)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        return self._sns_client.publish(
            TopicArn=self.topic_arn, Message=msg, Subject="Logging from the application"
        )
```

Note the call `msg = self.format(record)` in `emit`.  The built-in handlers do this too.