# Python logger: Prepending a string

Tags: python, django, logging

I have defined a logger as follows:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('APP')
syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(app_name)s : %(message)s')
app_name = {'app_name':'MULE'}
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, app_name)
```

I am trying to prepend a string to every logger message.
I have added this code based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657771/python-logger-formatting-is-not-formatting-the-string) and other similar questions. The problem is that now the logger is printing out 2 statements for every output that I want. The output is as  follows:

```
[03/Dec/2015 12:05:59] INFO views 91 1399960 [APP:1075] Picked
MULE : Picked
```

Why is this happening? Where am I going wrong?