# Pytest calling same function in multiple tests causing a leak

Tags: python, inheritance, logging, pytest, fixtures

I have a function where I am doing some logging like so:

```
class Foo:
    def start(file):
        with open(file, 'r') as r:
            d = json.load(r)
        if "a" in d:
            log.debug("a in file")
        elif "b" in d:
            log.debug("b in file")
```

`log` is a `logging` object declared in the parent class of this function. When I use pytest to test the logging works correctly like so:

```
def test_logging_a(caplog):
    # open file that has "a" as key in dict
    file_a = # path to file a

    ff = Foo()
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        ff.start(file_a)
    assert "a in file" in caplog.text


def test_logging_b(caplog):
    # open file that has "b" as key in dict
    file_b = # path to file b

    ff = Foo()
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        ff.start(file_b)
    assert "b in file" in caplog.text
```

Both these tests pass. However, when I run `pytest` with logs in output `pytest -s ...` I get the log `"b in file"` twice. If I comment out the first test (**or just comment out the call to `start()`**) `"b in file"` is only logged once (as it should).

**It seems like the tests are leaking.** If I reverse the order of the test i.e. `test_logging_b` runs before `test_logging_a`, the same thing happens but in reverse, `"a in file"` is shown twice in console like it is running twice.

Why is this happening? I also tried to instantiate `ff = Foo()` once in a `fixture` but the same thing happened.

Comment: Most probably you are adding the handlers to the logger twice.

Answer (score 0):

If handlers are being added to logger from inside the function that is being called multiple times, then that is the reason why this is happening. For example if `StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` is being added from a function that is called 5 times than logs will show up 5 times.

Handlers are not overridden but appended to. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729268/log-messages-appearing-twice-with-python-logging) should help.